# Getting error - Npgsql.NpgsqlOperationInProgressException: 'A command is already in progress: SELECT c."Id"

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql

We are migrating our netcore project from 2.2 to 6. And we are getting error message Npgsql.NpgsqlOperationInProgressException: 'A command is already in progress: SELECT ..
We have upgraded postgre and entity framework nudget packages as well to latest and stable one.
Earlier, same code was working perfectly fine. I have gone through several online links for the same error and per them it is happening as Postgre doesn't support the MARS. However, earlier it was working fine then how it's possible? Is Postgre doesn't support MARS after 2.2 version?

We are calling select statment inside the foreach loop. Please find the code snippet below:

```
 var obj = service.GetData().Select(o => new Object
            {
                Id = o.Id,
                Title = o.Title,
                AdminId = service.GetAdminId(o.Id)
            }).ToList();
```

```
public int GetAdminId(int id)
        {
            var obj = unitOfWork.Repository<entity>().GetSingle(x => x.IsActive && x.cId == id);
            return obj.adminId;
        }
```

I am stuck with this upgradation process so please provide you input

Please provide some light on it if Postgre doesn't support MARS then how we can resolve this issue

Comment: You can't use the same connection for simultaneous queries/commands. Open another connection or call `GetAdminId()` before `GetData()`

Comment: can't call GetData() after GetAdminId() as get admin function takes input from GetData. And earlier it was working fine and still working fine on netcore 2.2 version. So, any clue how it is working fine in old version?

Comment: Probably because EF Core 2.2, ignored non translatable `Select` from SQL generation, loaded whole recordset and then applied projection. Append `ToList()` to the query `service.GetData().ToList()..` - it will mimic EF Core 2.2 behaviour.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv - thanks for explanation!! ToList() worked !